# How to access data in foreign key table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables - Book and Ticket(id,borrowingDate,landingDate,idBook) - 
I need a method that verifies if a book is available or not using my DateTime properties; if borrowingDate is null -> available book
There are my model classes: 
Book:

```
 public class Book
    {
        public Book()
        {

        }
        [Key]
        public int IdBook { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Author")]
        public int IdAuthor{ get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    }
```

Ticket:

```
  public class Ticket
    {
        public Ticket()
        {

        }

        [Key]
        public int IdTicket { get; set; }
        public DateTime BorrowingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EstimatedLandingDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LandingTime { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Book")]
        public int IdBook { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: 1) we do not write your code for you, you are missing your main code 2) in your ticket class why are you pulling both the entire book class and int idBook if id book is already in the book class? 3) you do not need to have a collection of tickets in the book class especially if you are putting book class back in tickets, if you decide to fully populate one of these based on the other your are going to run into an endless loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

var availableBooks = books.Where(b => b.Tickets.Where(t => t.BorrowingDate    ==  null).Count() == 0).ToList();

This assumes BorrowingDate  is nullable (which is not the case in your model). If it isn't you'll have to compare with "DateTime.MinValue" instead of null